# How to lock orientation for iPhone for certain view controllers - Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, model-view-controller, screen-orientation

I have 2 View Controllers, VC1 and VC2.

VC1 currently presents VC2 modally.

VC1 only orientation should be portrait but VC2 can have all orientations.

The issue is when I am in VC2 and I rotate to landscape mode and then dismiss, VC1 is in landscape mode also! That should never happen!

**NOTE:** There is no Navigation Controller or UITabbarcontroller

I am adding my code bellow.

**Appdelagate**:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController) {
        if (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) {
            // Unlock landscape view orientations for this view controller
            return .allButUpsideDown
        }
    }

    // Only allow portrait (standard behaviour)
    return .portrait;
}

private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    if (rootViewController == nil) { return nil }
    if (rootViewController.isKind(of: (UITabBarController).self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.isKind(of:(UINavigationController).self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
```

Code in **VC2**:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
}

func canRotate() -> Void {}
```

Link to where I went for help and found this code
[Website where I found Code](http://www.jairobjunior.com/blog/2016/03/05/how-to-rotate-only-one-view-controller-to-landscape-in-ios-slash-swift/)

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You're doing this all wrong. Where are your implementations of [`supportedInterfaceOrientations`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations)? Both view controllers must have one.

Comment: I currently don't have that anywhere because I tried with it and it doesn't seem to work on iOS 10? Can you please elaborate a bit. Very new to this! I added a link to the question showing where I found this code

Comment: `supportedInterfaceOrientations` has been the preferred mechanism for handling device rotation since iOS 6 or so.  You don't mention how VC1 is presented but it seems likely that it should override that method to control it's rotation.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. Right now it is the root view controller on my test app but could change. Can you point me to the right direction on how to do this or she some code please?

Comment: Carefully read under the heading "Handling View Rotations" in the UIViewController documentation https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller?language=objc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to follow the below steps to lock rotation for specific ViewControllers :-

`Step 1:` While creating your project, allow all the orientations. Do not select anything in below image.
[image]
`Step 2:` If you want VC1 to have only Portrait Orientation the implementation then add the below two functions in your ViewController Class

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all //return the value as per the required orientation 
    }

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
```

`Step 3:` If you wish VC2 to have all the orientation then do not add any code for it.

**So the conclusion:-**

In project setting, allow all the orientations for whole project. Restriction should be at ViewControllers level not at project level.

If you wish any VC to have all orientation then don't write any code.

If you wish any VC to have specific orientation then implement two functions above.

Comment: Thanks for the help! In step 1) shouldn't everything be selected in order to allow all orientations?

Comment: By default, if you don't select anything then it allows all the orientation.

Comment: @user7097242 I hope it helped, Please accept the answer if it works for you. Cheers!

Comment: Will do after I try it out!

Comment: I tested your answer and it works perfect! But it also works if I have those check boxes selected then adding code you provided for the view controllers I wanted to lock in portrait. any suggestions?

Comment: The just select the portrait one and not the Upside Down. That one is not recommended. So it will lock in Portrait mode then. Cheers!