# Lock the orientation of the app in a specific View Controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, orientation

I'm working on an app that requires locking the orientation in each view controller.
I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795577/how-to-lock-orientation-for-iphone-for-certain-view-controllers-swift), but it did not work for me.
In the project settings, I set the device orientation to Portrait, Landscape Left, and Landscape right.

[image]

I have two view controllers, VC1 and VC2, and I want to lock the VC1's orientation vertically only. I want to lock the VC2's orientation, on the other hand, horizontally only.

Then I added the following code in VC1.

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait //return the value as per the required orientation
    }

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }
```

But, I can still able to rotate the VC1 horizontally...
Side note: VC1 contains a navigation bar and a tab bar.

If you know how to solve this issue, please let me know...

Comment: What if you monitor the change in orientation in each view controller and then change it to the desired one if the device orientation changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force orientation with few steps:

Firstly, In your `AppDelegate` define a orientation property and conform `supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor`

```swift
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return self.orientationLock
}
```

Then declare utility struct to set orientation using KVO:

```swift
struct AppOrientationUtility {
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) {
        if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
            delegate.orientationLock = orientation
        }
    }
        
    static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        self.lockOrientation(orientation)
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

How to use:

```swift
//For portrait
AppOrientationUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait)

//For landscape
AppOrientationUtility.lockOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight, andRotateTo: UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, son! Finally, I was able to solve this problem. I think I add the supportedInterfaceOrientations in each VC, but since I had nabnar and tabbar, I've had to add that line in AppDelegate. Anyway, thanks for your help and I really appreciate it :)